# PHP Regular expressions not working

Tags: php, regex

I've been using regexr.com to build and test regular expressions to use in my php programs. However, with this one particular expression, it seems to work on the website but not in the program and I am not sure why

I am trying to match EU label data (ex: G C 71) in the following string:

```
"Viking SnowTech II 165/70 R13 79T Winterreifen Auf Lager  G C 71  dBKundenbewertung (2.00) 29,50 € Details  In den Einkaufswagen"
```

the regular expression '#\s\w\s\w\s\d{1,}#' works fine on regexr.com but finds no match in my program

```
$eulab = $row_html -> plaintext;
        if( preg_match('#\s\w\s\w\s\d{1,}#', $eulab)){
            $insert['eulab'] =  $matches[0];

        }else {
            echo "No Match";
        }
```

i've tried other expressions too like \s{1}[A-Z]{1}\s{1}[A-Z]{1}\s{1}\d{1,}\s{1} which also work on regexr but find no match in my program. Could this be an encoding issue? or just my php syntax? No errors are being thrown.

Comment: I think you want to pass a 3rd parameter for the `$matches` ?! See: https://3v4l.org/VDhFM

Comment: Could also look at http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/e9W, which builds the function for you.

Comment: I originally had that... I just added it back and it still gives me no match. Which makes me think the problem is with $row_html -> plaintext. Could it be in a different encoding?

Comment: if instead of $eulab I put in the physical string it works but I need it not just for this single string but all strings that I pass this function

Comment: @Zane Do: `var_dump($row_html -> plaintext);` and take the output from the source code and put the relevant part here.

Comment: If you are viewing in a browser it is possible there are multiple whitespaces, the browser will only display one.

Comment: @chris85 You solved it! the browser was only displaying a single whitespace. Thank you so much

Comment: For reference, based on the spec for EU tire labels (http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32009R1222&from=EN), it is in the format of L L NNN, so you can match more exactly on it: `[A-Z]\s{1,}[A-Z]\s{1,}[0-9]{1,}`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the browser was only displaying a single whitespace when really there was more than that. I altered the expression to correct for that and it worked.

problem solved by @chris85 above

My final code and expression are:

```
        $eulab = $row_html -> plaintext;

        if( preg_match('#\s\w\s+\w\s+\d+#', $eulab, $matches)){

            $insert['eulab'] =  str_replace(" ", "", $matches[0]);
        }
```

Comment: You should add your updated regex. Also the `\d{1,}` could just be `\d+`. `+` is one or more of the preceding character.

Comment: Using UTF-8? You might want to investigate the /u pattern modifier. Or, in your case #u.